# ¿Cómo implementar el GroupBy para la generación de un Menu?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Buen día, estoy tratando de generar un menu con sus respectivos submenus usando GroupBy en C#, pero la agrupación no es la esperada, este es el código:

```
public class ItemsMenu
{
    public string Menu { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public int MenuOrder { get; set; }
    public string SubMenu { get; set; }
    public int SubMenuOrder { get; set; }
}

public class Keys
{
    public string Menu { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public int MenuOrder { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ItemsMenu> list = new();
        list.Add(new ItemsMenu() { Menu = "Menu2", Icon = "icon-2", MenuOrder = 2, SubMenu = "SubMenu-1", SubMenuOrder = 1 });
        list.Add(new ItemsMenu() { Menu = "Menu2", Icon = "icon-2", MenuOrder = 2, SubMenu = "SubMenu-2", SubMenuOrder = 2 });
        list.Add(new ItemsMenu() { Menu = "Menu2", Icon = "icon-2", MenuOrder = 2, SubMenu = "SubMenu-3", SubMenuOrder = 3 });
        list.Add(new ItemsMenu() { Menu = "Menu2", Icon = "icon-2", MenuOrder = 2, SubMenu = "SubMenu-4", SubMenuOrder = 4 });
        list.Add(new ItemsMenu() { Menu = "Menu1", Icon = "icon-1", MenuOrder = 1, SubMenu = "SubMenu-1", SubMenuOrder = 1 });
        list.Add(new ItemsMenu() { Menu = "Menu1", Icon = "icon-1", MenuOrder = 1, SubMenu = "SubMenu-2", SubMenuOrder = 2 });


        var order = list.OrderBy(x => x.MenuOrder).ThenBy(y => y.SubMenuOrder);
        var results = order.GroupBy(x => new Keys { Menu = x.Menu, Icon = x.Icon, MenuOrder = x.MenuOrder });

        foreach (var menu in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(menu.Key.Menu);
            foreach (var sm in menu)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sm.SubMenu);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

El resultado que me muestra es el siguiente:

Menu1
SubMenu-1
Menu1
SubMenu-2
Menu2
SubMenu-1
Menu2
SubMenu-2
Menu2
SubMenu-3
Menu2
SubMenu-4

Estoy buscando un resultado como el siguiente:

Menu1
SubMenu-1
SubMenu-2
Menu2
SubMenu-1
SubMenu-2
SubMenu-3
SubMenu-4

Cabe mencionar que anteriormente si funcionaba con .net framework, pero ahora estoy usando .net core, les agradezco de antemano su ayuda.

Comment: no hay una diferencia en linq para ninguno de las versiones de .net.. deberia darte lo mismo.. estas seguro que estas probando exactamente lo mismo?

Comment: Si, de hecho copie y pegue el código tal cual, solo me ordena si en el order by pongo un campo y no un objeto

Comment: Socio alguna diferencia tiene q existir, linq es igual para todas las versiones

Comment: Gracias por la observación, revisaré la implementación anterior para ver cuál es la diferencia